# jmeter cache doesn't clear in the next iteration

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I've faced the problem that JMeter doesn't clear the cache and extract variables in the next loop iteration, ruining the following request in the next loop.
[problem itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avo8s.png)

1. I tried check-box 'Clear cache each iteration.
2. Then I turned off the cache manager at all, but at the beginning of the next loop, I noticed that variables were left from the previous one.
   [1-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDDkt.png)
3. I even ad the pre-processor at the beginning of the scenario to remove all variables and clear the cache. Didn't help.
   [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrrQb.png)

Answer (score 0):

JMeter **does clear** the cache, here is the evidence:

[image]

As you can see

- when the box is ticket both requests download [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter)
- when the box is not ticked 2nd request only fetches HTML DOM, no requests to embedded resources are made

So most probably your expectations regarding how [HTTP caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) should work are a little bit wrong.

Also JMeter doesn't "clear" any defined variables so you might see "old" values during the next iteration, if you have [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers) which rely on certain variables presence - you need to reset the values manually somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Have spoken with my colleague about it and he said that it's well-known bug in JMeter.
More details are described here:
https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins/c/3RU_O9JXiYw/m/aovwl1SuAQAJ?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer&pli=1